# first pixel address of bitmap object on android

Tags: android

On visual studio c# .net framework for windows, there is `Bitmapdata.scan0` that get first pixel address of bitmap object. Is there a class or method on android that can do same? How to find first pixel address of bitmap object on android?

Comment: if you got bitmap you all pixels. what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The pixels in android Bitmaps are stored as an array.

All you have to do is:

> Bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

That method will return the pixel stored in the position x, y, and the bitmap range is:

0 - with on X

and 
0 - height on Y.

So you have to do a sweep through all the table to get each pixel as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bmp.getHeight(); i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < bmp.getWidth(); j++){
         int pixel = bmp.getPixel(j, i);
   }
}
```

Hope this Helps.

Regards!

Comment: Thank you,but method of getpixel get color of pixel(x,y),I want first pixel address to write bitmap object directly because setpixel and getpixel use more memory and cpu.

Answer (score 0):

Say your bitmap is:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
```

Provided it's initialized and holds data, you can get the first pixel with:

```
int color = bitmap.getPixel(0, 0);
```